# Column Value in Line and Stacked Column Chart as % of the column and not of the Grand Total

Tags: powerbi, hierarchy, percentage, drilldown, column-chart

I've got this doubt, in a Line and Stacked Column Chart I've got this:

[image]

But what I really need to show is the percentage of every series for each column, and keep this behavior when I go up or down in the hierarchy of the axis. For the image: (4/37), (6/37), (16/37) and so on.

Is there a way to reach this?

I looked for a possible solution even trying to create a metric for this but nothing worked.

Comment: Can you share what you've currently written for the measures involved?

Comment: It was something very simple, a calculation between the metrics with a filter by country. The problem is, how to make it dynamic with the hierarchy?

Comment: Adapt the existing calculation so that it's dynamic. It's impossible to say how for certain without seeing how the current measure is produced. It probably involves adapting the modifiers within CALCULATE.

Comment: I'm not so sure about you comment. There is not a current measure. I'm just using the properties of chart: I just drag the ID column on the column value section and choose an operation (% of grand total, count distinct...).

Comment: Ah ok, it's an automatically generated measure.

Answer (score 0):

The solution should probably look something like the following.

First a measure to count the rows:

```
CountMyRows := CountRows(MyTableName)
```

Second a measure that removes all filters other than the country from the count:

```
CountCountryRows := CALCULATE(CountMyRows, ALLEXCEPT(MyTableName,MyTableName[Country]))
```

Finally a measure to divide the two:

```
PercentOfCountry := DIVIDE(CountMyRows ,CountCountryRows )
```

The syntax may need some tweaking, without sample data or actual field and table names I'm guessing on a few things but the general approach should be correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replay BarneyL. That's exactly my problem, I need this to be dynamic. I need to show the calculation for all the possible shared axis..

Comment: Great. Is it working now? If this is the solution then it's helpful for others to flag it as the question answer.